# Odoo Customization

Tags: openerp-7, odoo

I have developed a module named as student information and files as well as content details are as follows.

1) **init**.py

```
import student_info
```

2) **openerp**.py

```
{
'name' : 'Student Information',
'version' : '6.0.1',
'author' : 'RANA',
'website' : 'http://www.tuespacioweb.com.ve',
'category' : 'General',
'depends' : ['base'],
'description' : '''Information about Students''',
'init_xml':[],
'update_xml':['student_info_view.xml'],
'demo_xml' : [],
'active':False,
"data" : [ "student_view.xml"],
"installable": True,
"certificate" : ''
}
```

3) Student_info.py

```
from openerp.osv import fields, orm

class student_student(osv.osv):

_name = 'student.student'

_columns = {
        'name' : fields.char('Student Name', size=16, required = True, translate=True),
        'age' : fields.integer('Age',readonly = True),
        'percent' : fields.float('Percentage',help = 'This field will add average marks of     student out of 100.'),
        'gender' : fields.selection([('male','Male'),('female','Female')],'Gender'),
        'active' : fields.boolean('Active'),
        'notes' : fields.text('Details'),
        }

_defaults = { 'name' : 'Atul',
    'active' : True,                    
}

student_student()
```

4) Student_info_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<!-- Student search view -->

<record model="ir.ui.view" id="student_search">
<field name="name">student.search</field>
<field name="model">student.student</field>
<field name="type">search</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<search string="Student Information Search">
    <field name="name" string="Student Name" />
    <field name="gender" string="Gender" />
    <field name="age" string="Age" />
</search>
</field>
</record>

<!-- Student tree view -->

<record id='student_student_tree' model='ir.ui.view'>
<field name='name'>student.result.tree</field>
<field name='model'>student.student</field>
<field name='type'>tree</field>
<field name='arch' type='xml'>
    <tree string="Student_result">
        <field name="name" />
        <field name="age" />
        <field name="percent" />
        <field name="gender" />
        <field name="active" />
    </tree>
</field>
</record>

<!--Student Form View-->

<record id='student_student_form' model='ir.ui.view'>
<field name="name">student.result.form</field>
<field name="model">student.student</field>
<field name="type">form</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form string="Student_result">
        <field name="name" />
        <field name="age" />
        <field name="percent" />
        <field name="gender" />
        <field name="active" />
        <field name="notes" />
    </form>
</field>
</record>

<!-- Student Action-->

<record id="action_student_student" model="ir.actions.act_window">
<field name='name'>Student Information</field>
<field name='res_model'>student.student</field>
<field name='view_type'>form</field>
<field name='view_mode'>tree,form</field>
</record>

<!--Student Menu-->

<menuitem id="student_parent" name="Student" icon="terp-partner"/>
<menuitem id="menu_student_parent" name="Student Management" parent="student_parent"></menuitem>
<menuitem action="action_student_student" id="menu_student_student" parent="menu_student_parent"    string="Result"/>

</data>
</openerp>
```

Now, after all that: Error I am now receving after installing module from Openerp localhost is given below:

My Error after doing exactly what you said is:

Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\http.py", line 204, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1132, in call_button
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1120, in _call_kw
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 42, in proxy
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 103, in send

Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 89, in send
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server.\openerp\netsvc.py", line 296, in dispatch_rpc
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server.\openerp\service\web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 199, in execute
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server\openerp\addons\base\module\module.py", line 426, in button_immediate_install
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server\openerp\addons\base\module\module.py", line 477, in _button_immediate_function
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server.\openerp\pooler.py", line 39, in restart_pool
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server.\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 233, in new
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 354, in load_modules
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 254, in load_marked_modules
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server.\openerp\modules\graph.py", line 102, in add_modules
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server.\openerp\modules\module.py", line 344, in load_information_from_description_file
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server.\openerp\tools\safe_eval.py", line 285, in safe_eval
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server.\openerp\tools\safe_eval.py", line 158, in test_expr
  File "", line 15
    schoolsout.py
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Ok

Please Guide me about these errors... Thanks a lot

Comment: do you have another `.py file` ? because it's showing line 15 schoolsout.py and error came of syntax. please check out `.py` file.

Comment: I have compiled files there... No such other py file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have compile your files. Now iI able to install your module. Main Cause I found is that

1) Given Multiline comment in **openerp**.py file.

2) Edit the file Student_info.py as following line

```
from openerp.osv import fields, orm
```

to

```
from openerp.osv import fields, **osv**
```

Use the python block for classes. i.e

```
class student_student(osv.osv):

XXX
```

should (all code under class student_student) be aligned as (Tab all code[XXX] inside the class)

```
class student_student(osv.osv):

<TAB>  XXX
```

3) Edit the file **init**.py as following line: Class name here is case sensitive (Capital S)

```
import student_info
```

to

```
import Student_info
```

I have attached my code.

### **openerp**.py

```
#Remove multiline comment here if any present

{
    'name':'Student Information',
    'version':'6.0.1',
    'author':'RANA',
    'website':'http://www.tuespacioweb.com.ve',
    'category':'General',
    'depends':['base'],
    'description':'''
    Information about Students''',
    'init_xml':[],
    'update_xml':['Student_info_view.xml'],
    'demo_xml':[],
    'active':False,
    'installable':True,
    "certificate" : '',

}
```

### Student_info.py

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class student_student(osv.osv):

    _name = 'student.student'

    _columns = {
            'name' : fields.char('Student Name', size=16, required = True, translate=True),
            'age' : fields.integer('Age',readonly = True),
            'percent' : fields.float('Percentage',help = 'This field will add average marks of     student out of 100.'),
            'gender' : fields.selection([('male','Male'),('female','Female')],'Gender'),
            'active' : fields.boolean('Active'),
            'notes' : fields.text('Details'),
            }

    _defaults = { 'name' : 'Atul',
        'active' : True,                    
    }

student_student()
```

### **init**.py

```
import Student_info
```

No change in Student_info_view.xml